# Amazon AWS CLI: How do I find out what actions/permissions/policies are attributed to a role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm on Linux and using the AWS CLI.

I tried running the following:

- `aws iam list-instance-profiles-for-role --role-name role-abc-123`
- `aws iam get-role --role-name role-abc-123 --query 'Role.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Action[]'`
- `aws iam list-attached-role-policies --role-name role-abc-123`

However each one comes back with:

`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the XXX operation: User: YYY is not authorized to perform: XXX on resource: role ZZZ because no identity-based policy allows the XXX action`

How would I see what actions I'm able to perform, what policy is against the role and which actions are against that policy?

Thanks

Comment: You need permission to access IAM in order to get the policies attached.